How can I run a specific Python function from the Powershell console?
How can I run a specific function from the Powershell (or, for that matter, any other) terminal?
What is missing from my python file ?
I have a python file my_file.py :
def func1():
    print('first function')

def func2():
    print('second function')

I have tried running python -m my_file func2, but I am not getting the expected output.
What am I missing?

Sorry about the initial mixup - I wasn't thinking straight. The duplicate target should now be correct.

You can use python -c cmd:
py_file.py:
def func():
    print ("test")

run in Powershell:
python -c "from py_file import func; func()" // outputs test

You can execute arbitrary python statements using -c argument:
for example:
python -c "from my_file import *; func1()"

